# How to turn "debugger;" off

Tags: javascript, browser

I recently encountered a website that abuses the `debugger;` functionality to prevent effective use of the F12 developer tools. It calls `debugger;` in several `setInterval` and all over the place in functions.

Then they have timing tracking variables that terminate the website functionality if the debugger is stopped at a breakpoint for a few seconds..

Is there a way to switch off this functionality and only have the debugger break where I ask? (via breakpoint)

I've been thinking that something like

```
window.debugger = "function() return 0;" ;
```

would work, but it didnt :'(

Comment: Doesn't `Ctrl + F8` work?

Comment: No idea, what does it do?

Comment: `debugger` is a statement like `if`, not a function. You cannot change its behavior. The runtime environment would have provide an option to do that.

Comment: In Chrome, Ctrl+F8 helps you ignore `debugger` statement

Comment: i'll give it a try, anything cross browser? or is this a browser specific problem?